# Cannot create an instance of unrecognized alias: widget.[object Object]

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I have been trying to add a custom class into one of my views but when I run the application, I get an error in the console log "Cannot create an instance of unrecognized alias: widget.[object Object]". My code is as follows:

SubCategoryListView.js

```
Ext.define('RestaurantGlobal.view.SubCategoryListView',{
      extend: 'Ext.List',
      xtype: 'SubCategoryListView',

      requires: ['RestaurantGlobal.store.ItemColumnsStore'],

config:{
    items:[
        {
            xtype: Ext.create('Ext.List', {
                fullscreen: true,
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    docked: 'top',
                    ui: 'neutral',
                    items: [
                        {
                            text:'Veg',
                            align :'center',
                            handler: function () {
                                var sto = Ext.create('RestaurantGlobal.store.ItemColumnsStore');
                                // clear all existing filters
                                sto.clearFilter();
                                sto.filter('Info2', 'False');
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text:'Non-Veg',
                            align :'center',
                            handler: function () {
                                var sto = Ext.create('RestaurantGlobal.store.ItemColumnsStore');
                                // clear all existing filters
                                sto.clearFilter();
                                sto.filter('Info2', 'True');
                            }
                        },
                    ],
                    store: 'RestaurantGlobal.store.ItemColumnsStore',
                    itemTpl: ['{Name}  {Image}']
                }],
            }),
        }
    ]
  }
});
```

SubCategories.js

```
     Ext.define('RestaurantGlobal.view.SubCategories', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',

requires : ['RestaurantGlobal.view.SubCategoryListView'],

config: {
    styleHtmlCls: 'maincontainer',
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox'
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            flex: 0.5,
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Category Name'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'SubCategoryListView',
        },

            {
            xtype: 'container',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    docked: 'bottom',
                    margin: '0 0 0 0',
                    text: 'Place Order'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  }
});
```

Please help me in this regard. Also, is there a way to filter a single store to display them into 2 tabs in the same tabpanel?

I am not using tab panel in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is this:

```
xtype: Ext.create('Ext.List', {
```

`xtype` must be a string.

You can theoritically put a component instance directly in the `items`:

```
items:[
    Ext.create('Ext.List', {
        fullscreen: true,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            ui: 'neutral',
            items: [
                {
                    text:'Veg',
                    align :'center',
                    handler: function () {
                        var sto = Ext.create('RestaurantGlobal.store.ItemColumnsStore');
                        // clear all existing filters
                        sto.clearFilter();
                        sto.filter('Info2', 'False');
                    }
                },
                {
                    text:'Non-Veg',
                    align :'center',
                    handler: function () {
                        var sto = Ext.create('RestaurantGlobal.store.ItemColumnsStore');
                        // clear all existing filters
                        sto.clearFilter();
                        sto.filter('Info2', 'True');
                    }
                },
            ],
            store: 'RestaurantGlobal.store.ItemColumnsStore',
            itemTpl: ['{Name}  {Image}']
        }],
    }
]
```

But in the context of a class definition that would really be ill inspired because this same component instance would be used by every instance you create of your class. Most probably resulting in a lot of problems...

In case you *really* need to create the component instance yourself, because you can't simply declare its configuration, do it by overriding the `initComponent` method, and create your component in there. The `initComponent` method will be called for each new instance of your class, so each one will have its own instance of the child component (sorry, I know that makes a lot of repetitions of the word "instance").

Anyway, it seems that what you are really trying to do is simply to override the list class:

```
Ext.define('RestaurantGlobal.view.SubCategoryListView',{
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'SubCategoryListView',

    requires: ['RestaurantGlobal.store.ItemColumnsStore'],

    // You class is already a list, just add your custom configuration
    // directly to it:
    config:{
        fullscreen: true,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            ui: 'neutral',
            items: [{
                text:'Veg',
                align :'center',
                handler: function () {
                    var sto = Ext.create('RestaurantGlobal.store.ItemColumnsStore');
                    // clear all existing filters
                    sto.clearFilter();
                    sto.filter('Info2', 'False');
                }
            },{
                text:'Non-Veg',
                align :'center',
                handler: function () {
                    var sto = Ext.create('RestaurantGlobal.store.ItemColumnsStore');
                    // clear all existing filters
                    sto.clearFilter();
                    sto.filter('Info2', 'True');
                }
            }],
            store: 'RestaurantGlobal.store.ItemColumnsStore',
            itemTpl: ['{Name}  {Image}']
        }]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('RestaurantGlobal.view.SubCategoryListView',{
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    *xtype: 'SubCategoryListView',*
```

The problem is that you used xtype in class definition but it could be alias:

```
Ext.define('RestaurantGlobal.view.SubCategoryListView',{
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    alias: 'widget.SubCategoryListView',
```

and then you can use this class to create list in this case by:

```
xtype: 'SubCategoryListView'
```

as you expected.